# Rounded corners in GroupBox control

Tags: .net, winforms, controls, groupbox

How can I get rounded corners in a GroupBox in my form? Is there any option in the property tab?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When [visual styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.renderwithvisualstyles.aspx) are enabled for your application and the [`FlatStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.groupbox.flatstyle.aspx) property is set to "System", the group boxes look like they have *slightly* rounded corners, but it's probably no more than 3 to 5 degrees. So I suppose this is not what you're looking for.

**Unfortunately, there's no built-in way to customize its degree of roundedness. The only real solution is to use a custom control.** You can either inherit off of the existing `GroupBox` control and override its `Paint` event to draw the borders yourself, or you can use one of these existing controls:

- http://roundedgroupbox.codeplex.com/
- http://weblogs.asp.net/andrewrea/archive/2008/02/18/my-own-version-of-a-winforms-rounded-groupbox-with-transparency.aspx
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/grouper.aspx

Comment: Just overdraw the control over a bitmap with the right corners' shape ;)

Comment: The last one is the best for me. Worked fine. I'm just trying to figure out how to put it in my toolbox as in the demo source code.

Comment: @Jack Not entirely sure what you mean, but if you want a custom control to appear in your toolbox, you can try turning on Options -> Windows Forms Designer -> AutoToolboxPopulate. That way, when you rebuild the solution, user controls will appear automatically in your toolbox.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8931328/how-do-i-add-my-new-user-control-to-the-toolbox-or-a-new-winform

Comment: @CodyGray: In the demo project the custom rouded group box control is available on the toolbox so you can drag-and-drop it. I want to do the same to my project, importing the dll as right click toolbox -> select intem -> browse dll didn't worked so I created an empty cs file and added a class  `public class MyGrouper : Grouper { }` so that it gets added in the toolbox automatically (as it's a class that inherit from a control) after the first compilation. This isn't really a elegant solution but was how I managed to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this open source controls:
http://roundedgroupbox.codeplex.com/